# UnsupportedOperationException when trying to remove a list of items from another list

Tags: java, listiterator

I have coded below, i dint know what is wrong but validDatesIterator.remove() is giving me UnsupportedOperationException exception. Using java 1.6

```
List<Integer> validDates = Arrays.asList(26,27,28,1,2,3,4);
    List<Integer> daysToBeRemoved = Arrays.asList(1,2); 
    Iterator<Integer> validDatesIterator = validDates.listIterator();
    while(validDatesIterator.hasNext()) {
        Integer curValue = validDatesIterator.next();
        for(Integer dayToRemove:daysToBeRemoved) {
            if(curValue.equals(dayToRemove)) {
                validDatesIterator.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Also When i debug valid dates(curValue initially it gives 27, instead 26) is starting with element 27, not 26.

May be a duplicate question, but searched a lot, dint find kinda of this. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Comment: Can you use List#removeAll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` returns `Arrays.ArrayList`, a `List` implementation that doesnt support the removal of elements. Use

```
List<Integer> validDates = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(26,27,28,1,2,3,4));
```

Answer (score 1):

First problem: `Arrays.asList()` returns an (basically) unmodifiable list. Pass it to the constructor of a normal List.

Second problem: You have reinvented the wheel.

Try this:

```
List<Integer> validDates = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(26,27,28,1,2,3,4));
List<Integer> daysToBeRemoved = Arrays.asList(1,2);

validDates.removeAll(daysToBeRemoved);
```